# Specify comments in JPQL named queries

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

We have some scenario where 2 applications points to the same oracle database/tables and perform some queries.
DB Team suggested to use comments in SQL that helps them to identify who should they contact to for slow running queries.

Since we are using the JPA i am not sure **how can we define comments** for the JPQL queries that are converted into native SQL by JPA.
If we specify the comments in JPQL then it breaks

```
        @NamedQuery(name = Consts.LOOKUP_BY_END_DATE, query = "
/* comment */ SELECT b FROM TableB b WHERE "
                + " b.id.ObjId=:ObjId AND b.id.persId=:persId and b.recEffEndDayKy=:recEffEndDayKy "),
```

Exception :

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [/* comments */SELECT b FROM TableB b WHERE  b.id.ObjId=:ObjId AND b.id.PersId=:PersId and b.recEffEndDayKy=:recEffEndDayKy ]. 
[0, 157] The query does not start with a valid identifier, has to be either SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE FROM.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.JPAQuery.processJPQLQuery(JPAQuery.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.JPAQuery.prepare(JPAQuery.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.prepareInternal(DatabaseQuery.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.processJPAQuery(AbstractSession.java:4366)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.processJPAQueries(AbstractSession.java:4326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:731)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: JPQL BNF is very clear that there is no such concept of a "comment". I've no idea what a "JPA generated query" is ... JPA does not generate queries, the user does

Comment: When you write Named Query in JPQL, this is not the query that runs against the DB. JPA convert JPQL into native SQL and runs on DB.

When we call persist/merge/remove on entity manager, it actually generate INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries that runs on the target database.

Comment: And as I said ... you cannot have a COMMENT in JPQL. It is ILLEGAL syntax. So it won't convert to SQL. The message tells you this ... your query (JPQL) has to start with a valid keyword (SELECT)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have confused native queries which accept SQL with named JPQL queries.  JPQL doesn't support comments.  If you want to control the query, you will have to use SQL, or use native EclipseLink functionality.  See the 'SQL' function described here http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/05/jpql-vs-sql-have-both-with-eclipselink.html

Comment: Nopes, I am not confused with native SQL queries :)
That is why i mentioned explicitly in subject and explanation JPA Generated queries

Comment: check out the link then, as the only way to get something added to the generated SQL will be through the 'SQL' keyword provided by EclipseLink.

Answer (score 0):

Hints can be used with @NamedQuery to specify the comments,for example:

```
@NamedQuery(name="someQuery",
        query="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL",
        hints={@QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.comment", value="very_important_comment")})
```